# Joining multiple tables using Sqoop from MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, hive, mariadb

I have tried the following sqoop command. It works for joining two tables but not for multiple tables:

```
sqoop import 
--connect jdbc:mysql://<ip>:6306/siki_asmet?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull 
--username micronics -P 
--query "SELECT * from bu FULL JOIN bu_brbu USING(id_bu) FULL JOIN bu_jenis USING(id_jenis_bu) WHERE \$CONDITIONS" 
--split-by bu.id_bu 
--target-dir /user/hadoop/joinbu -m 1;
```

It says there's error in the syntax:

```
ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL JOIN bu_jenis USING(id_jenis_bu) WHERE  (1 = 0)' at line 1
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL JOIN bu_jenis USING(id_jenis_bu) WHERE  (1 = 0)' at line 1
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
```

I can't use JOIN ON because then it gives me error saying column not recognized.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no FULL JOIN in MySQL.

You could emulate it using unions of left join (or left and right).
You can see below an example based on your tables:

```
Select * from bu left join bu_brbu on condition
union all
select * from bu right join bu_brbu on condition
```